# ./node_modules/primeng/fesm2015/primeng-accordion.js 94:208-226 "export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget'

Tags: angular, primeng

i have download an angular free template , when i want to install the **PrimeNg** and add my imports inside the module.ts , it dispaly me this error

```
./node_modules/primeng/fesm2015/primeng-accordion.js 94:208-226
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
```

Answer (score 1):

As per @AliF50 suggestion, both versions should be compatible to avoid this error.

In my case

```
  "@angular/animations": "^11.2.14",
"@angular/common": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/compiler": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/core": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/elements": "^11.2.14",
"@angular/forms": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/router": "~11.2.14",
"@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.2.0",
"@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.1.2",
"concat": "^1.0.3",
"document-register-element": "^1.7.2",
"ngx-build-plus": "^11.0.0",
"primeicons": "^4.1.0",
"primeng": "^11.2.3",
```

Angular is 11.12 and the nearest equivalent primeng is Angular 11.2.3

Once you have proper versions:

Step 1: Remove the node_modules folder from the directory.

Step 2: Then run the `npm install`

Step 3: Then run `ng s`

It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

What version of `Angular` are you using? Make sure you install the compatible version of `PrimeNg` found here https://www.npmjs.com/package/primeng.

In essence, if you're using version 7 of Angular, use version `7.1.3` of PrimeNg.

Comment: i have check the compatibility version of the both , and they have the same version